# Find x documents before/after a target document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to construct relative leaderboard using MongooseJS. Given the following data (simplified):

```
{
   user: 1,
   score: 10
},
{
   user: 1,
   score: 5
},
{
   user: 2,
   score: 3
},
{
   user: 3,
   score: 5
},
{
   user: 3,
   score: 3
},
{
   user: 4,
   score: 2
}
```

And the following query:

```
ActionLog.model.aggregate()
        .group({_id: '$user',totalScore:{$sum:'$score'}})
        .sort('-totalScore')
        .limit(3)
        .exec(function(err, logs){
            if(err) { return res.apiError('1103', Errors['1103']); }
            User.model.populate(logs, {path: '_id', select:'username'}, function(err) {
                return res.apiResponse(logs);
         });
});
```

I would get a result of 3 Users (users 1, 3 and 2) with their totalScore sorted by the totalScore. Which works great. However say I would like to get a relative leaderboard, where I get the highscores of the player in front and behind me. For example, the relative leaderboard for player 2 would have to return something like:

```
{
   _id: {
        "_id": "3",
        "username": "David"
   },
   totalScore: 8
},
{
   _id: {
        "_id": "2",
        "username": "Elsa"
   },
   totalScor: 3
},
{
   _id: {
        "_id": "4",
        "username": "John"
   },
   totalScore: 2
}
```

How do I get that?

Comment: Use 2 queries to get results above and below the center, sorted in the right order.